# Symfony Controller findBy() not working with variable

Tags: symfony, controller, findby

I try to use findBy() in my controller and it only works when I use plain text and not a variable - but both are strings, for example:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SchlauchBundle:Armatur');

$armatur = $entity->getArmatur();

$armaturen = $repository->findBy(
    array('nameArmatur' => $entity->getArmatur())
);
```

var_dump($armatur) outputs:
`string(21) "Klemmschalen EN 14420"`

but var_dump($armaturen) outputs:
`NULL`.

When I change the findBy()-part to:

```
$armaturen = $repository->findBy(
    array('nameArmatur' => "Klemmschalen EN 14420")
);
```

it works - it is so confusing me! What could be the problem that it is not possible for me to use the variable? I don't understand the difference.

In entity file it's defined (nothing special):

```
/**
* @var string
*/
private $nameArmatur;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a trim(array('nameArmatur' => $entity->getArmatur()) to see what's the behaviour

Comment: this doesn't change anything - same thing

Answer (score 0):

I use the following styling which will just work fine -

```
$marker = $em->getRepository('SkerpGenericBundle:Marker')->findBy(array('userid' => $userObj->getId()));
```

Thats strange! I didnt face that kind of issue.

Comment: it seems that there is another mainproblem  - sometimes it doens't work with plain text. I don't know what's the issue - the field from database exists and is filled with exactly that string. And why it works and sometimes not is a mystery. When I do it like your way, it works when I pull something from the database which is related to the controller.

Comment: can you please add your $entity object code and $entity dump in the above code. so that it will be very handy to debug

Comment: I added the part, not sure if it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `$entity->getArmatur()` might return an object with implemented `__toString` method.
Maybe try something like:

```
$armaturen = $repository->findBy(
    array('nameArmatur' => $entity->getArmatur()->__toString())
);
```